# How to call Observer on Reorder?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, reorder

I want to call an observer on reorder to get the order id.suggest me some solution.

Comment: You can get complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255536/magento-how-to-hook-into-order-reorder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the `controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_reorder` event and then get the order id parameter on the observer

```
$oldOrderId=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to reorder it from adminpanel or frontend. 
From the adminpanel you can use this event:

`controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_reorder`

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_reorder>
            <observers>
                <mynamespace_mymodule_controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_reorder>
                        <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_path_to_your_class</class>
                        <method>yourMethodName</method>
                </mynamespace_mymodule_controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_reorder>
             </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_reorder>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```